# Implement GetRoleAsync method with field in the Database

Tags: asp.net-core, user-controls, identity, blazor-server-side

I need to implement the role retrieval method in identity. Currently I do GetRoleAsync (id) and I pull out all user roles.
But when I remove a role from the user, I don't want to delete it, but deactivate it.
So I would like to tell GetRoleAsync (id) to pull out all roles with ENABLED = true

How can I do?

Comment: hello, unfortunately not.  It didn't help me because that Remove Role method deletes the record from the database, losing track of it completely.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use build-in [RemoveFromRoleAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.removefromroleasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method to remove role reference with current user:

```
//get current user
var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
//remove role from current user
await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, "TheRoleName");
```